# How to use openssl crypto lib?

Tags: openssl

can somebody advise me good "How to" or Manual. It is match micro articles how to use specific algorithms or very large books about crypto lib. 
I am trying to find something in between, something that would allow me to quickly start with this lib.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what kind of thing to you want to achieve with cryptographic libraries ? Secure communications ? Secure Storage ? Authentification ?

Comment: Block ciphers and MACs

Comment: I am interested to use cryptographic primitives from the library

Answer (score 2):

> Can somebody advise me good "How to" or Manual?

You can find HowTo's sprinkled across the web.

The manual is located online at [OpenSSL Documents](http://www.openssl.org/docs/). The same manual is installed locally, and you access it via the `man` pages. For example, you can find information on ciphers with *ciphers(1)*. You can find it online at [`ciphers(1)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html), or by typing `man 1 ciphers`.

You can also visit the [OpenSSL wiki](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Main_Page). Block ciphers are covered at [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) and [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption). MACs are covered at [EVP Message Digests](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests).

There are a couple of books, but they are a bit dated. They are still good reference since everything presented is still in use (there's just more stuff now). See [Network Security with OpenSSL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600270X) and [SSL and TLS: Designing and Building Secure Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615983).

Finally, when you can't find information on something, the last line is the source code. Nearly all functionality is demostrated in the various subcommands. For example, `pkcs8` is a subcommand in `openssl pkcs8 ...`. You can find the source code in `<openssl src dir>/apps/pkcs8.c`.